# the every() method not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, boolean

Can someone kindly tell me why this is returning true? It should return false because in the first iteration value[pre] === 0... Thanks.

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) { 
   function check(value){
      if(value.hasOwnProperty(pre)){
         return value[pre] !== null || value[pre] !== undefined || value[pre] !== ""|| value[pre] !== 0; 
      }
   } 
   return collection.every(check);
}    
truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male", "age": 0}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male", "age": 3}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female", "age": 5}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female", "age": 4}], "age");
```

Comment: you need to invert your logic. i.e. `return !(value[pre] === null || value[pre] === undefined || value[pre] === ""|| value[pre] === 0);`

Comment: Consider reading about De Morgan's Law. Also consider that every value is not `null` **or** not `undefined`.

Comment: Ok can you please explain why? I am saying if the array contains the property pre, and the value of pre does not equal null,undefined,"", or 0 , then return true (as it has passed the test) ?? Why is it that using the && operator works ? or reversing the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&` operator

```
return (value[pre] !== null 
        && value[pre] !== undefined 
        && value[pre] !== "" 
        && value[pre] !== 0);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4wcovask/

Comment: Thanks that works. But can you please explain why? because if I use the || operator, aren't I asking if ANY of these are not equal, then return false?

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost Using `||` is asking if any of these are not equal, then return true.

Comment: The expression can be condensed to `!!value[pre]` if you're just trying to see if the value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: _"aren't I asking if ANY of these are not equal, then return false?"_ No. Given `var value = 0;

if (value !== null || value !== undefined || value !== "" || value !== 0) {
  console.log(true)
}` the condition does not reach `value !== 0`

Comment: I see, it returns an answer before reaching value !== 0 ? because value already !-- null ?

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost Yes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/5743988) to see how using `!!` works.